# I am getting various warrnings and errors when trying to create react app with npx

Tags: linux, reactjs

I am trying to create react app with npx and get the following error: `error fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@1.5.0: The engine "yarn" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=1.0.0".`

Any ideas what could be the source of the issue? any tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

npx create-react-app food

```
npx: installed 91 in 5.566s

Creating a new React app in /home/oren/m/code/food.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v0.16.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
warning fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
warning fsevents@2.0.7: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.0.7" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
error fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@1.5.0: The engine "yarn" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=1.0.0".
error Found incompatible module
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd /home/oren/m/code/food has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting food/ from /home/oren/m/code
Done.
```

About my environment:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

---

```
$ uname -a
Linux oren 4.4.0-142-generic #168-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 16 21:00:45 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

node -v

```
v12.8.0
```

npm -v

```
6.10.2
```

Comment: Have you installed yarn? Check the version of yarn and update it to latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this line in the log `error fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@1.5.0: The engine "yarn" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=1.0.0"`. It says your yarn version is not compatible. You have yarn v0.16.1 but it has to be above 1.0.0. Please try to update your yarn version.

Answer (score 6):

I have solved by installing latest version of Yarn. 
- first uninstall version 
- installed latest version `npm install -g yarn`
- removing yarn cache folder in the AppData folder has solved my issue C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Yarn

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else is struggling with this even after uninstalling/reinstalling yarn from npm, for me I actually had an old version of yarn installed outside of npm or another package manager, and I had to uninstall it from the Add or Remove Programs list in Windows.

Comment: I just had this problem, this answer solved it for me.